# Java 8: IntStream to Integer[]

Tags: java, java-stream

I am writing simple program which will eventually plot the run times of various sorting algorithms written in Java. The general interface of a sorting algorithm is via a method: `public void sort(Comparable[] xs)`

I am attempting to use Java 8's stream mechanism to generate random test cases along the following lines:

```
public static IntStream testCase(int min, int max, int n) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    return generator.ints(min, max).limit(n);
}
```

My question is, how can I convert an object of type `IntStream` to an `Integer[]`?

Comment: Don’t use `ints(min, max).limit(n)` but just `ints(n, min, max)`. It’s not only shorter, given the current implementation and the fact that you want to collect into an array, it’ll be more efficient.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should [box](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`, then call [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) to make a array of it:

```
Integer[] arr = testCase(1,2,3).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: The key is `boxed()` the `IntStream` into a `Stream<Integer>`